# jQuery on('click') not working on dynamically generated page

Tags: jquery, express-handlebars

I'm using handlebars to dynamically generate html pages for a NodeJS project.
I have an event.js and a jquery.min.js file that are both loaded.

Here's part of the HTML :

```
<td>
    <input id="temps_ajout_resultat" name="temps" type="text" value="{{tempsMini}}" pattern="[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" title=" Format hh:mm:ss et au moins {{tempsMini}}">
</td>
<td>
    <input id="tempsMini_ajout_resultat" class="hidden" name="tempsMini" type="text" value="{{tempsMini}}">
    <input id="nbpoints" class="hidden" name="nbpoints" type="number" value="{{nbPointsSuivant}}">
    <input id="num" class="hidden" name="num" type="number" value="{{gpnum}}">
</td>
<td><button id="valider_ajout_resultat" type="button" value="Ajouter">Valider</button></td>
```

And part of the Javascript :

```
$('body').on('click', '#valider_ajout_resultat', function() {

    console.log('test');
    console.log($('body').find('#tempsMini_ajout_resultat').val());
    console.log($('body').find('#temps_ajout_resultat').val());

    validerTempsCourse($('body').find('#tempsMini_ajout_resultat').val(), $('body').find('#temps_ajout_resultat').val());});
```

The problem is that clicking on the "valider_ajout_resultat" button does absolutely nothing.
The console says nothing either.

Anyone sees the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Any [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) error?

Comment: No there isn't anything :/

Comment: Either you are misinterpreting results, or the problem is elsewhere. Are you sure that line of code even runs?

Comment: If you comment `validerTempsCourse(...)` line out... Do you have the console logs?

Comment: No still nothing

Comment: In the console... You can type commands in. Type `$.fn.jquery`. It should output the jQuery version you are using if it's loaded.

Comment: are you using any 3th party plugins, which maybe use `stopPropagation()` in body. did you try it with `document`?

Comment: It's using the 3.3.1 version.
Using 'document' doesn't change the problem no, I'm using express.

Comment: Maybe the `click` event is prevented somewhere... Try with `mouseup`.

Comment: mouseup didn't fix it either :/

Comment: There is a problem elsewhere then... I can't tell. The code you posted works [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/geKxjP?editors=1011).

Comment: Yeah I see... I guess Handlebars is doing weird stuff, but it used to work in classic Javascript until it suddenly glitched and I tried to convert it to jQuery.
If I don't find a solution I guess I'll have to trigger it in an html onClick.

Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

Can you edit the dynamically generated code?

You could put an `onclick` on the button and call a function:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="valider_ajout_resultat" type="button" value="Ajouter">Valider</button>
```

and then in your javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('test');
    console.log($('body').find('#tempsMini_ajout_resultat').val());
    console.log($('body').find('#temps_ajout_resultat').val());

    validerTempsCourse($('body').find('#tempsMini_ajout_resultat').val(), $('body').find('#temps_ajout_resultat').val());});
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Triggering it this way does work, but I really need to make it work the way I put it here for the following functions